# Regex to match my requirement

Tags: regex

Please help me with my requirement to match only specific pattern.

We have a string for example *Jeorge Sally (34)*. my application should always pick the value that matches the pattern *any name* with *(34)*.

I tried the following regex `[A-z (34)]*` but this is giving the different values also such as `Adam siva (`.

Thanks.

Comment: Check with `if (s.EndsWith("(34)"))`. A regex might be `^[a-zA-Z ]+\(34\)$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the regex you are looking for is something like this:

```
^[A-z]+\s[A-z]+\s\(34\)$
```

This will match any first name, a space, a last name and then the 34 in brackets. Notice the brackets are escaped using a backslash.

I recommend using an online tool such as [RegExr](http://regexr.com) or [Regex101](http://regex101.com) when you are trying to figure out where you are going wrong with your regular expressions as they provide visual aid to guide you.

Comment: Thank you for quick response and syntax .It is taking other numbers as 11 ,9 also. Is there a way i can make 34 as static

Comment: Hi @user3780032, using the regex I provided above, I get a match for `Jeorge Sally (34)` but not for `Jeorge Sally (24)` can you show the code that you are using to find the matches?

Comment: Somehow it is highlighting different ages in RPT tool . Is there a way we can make 34 as static value instead of dynamic value.

Comment: The 34 is required in order for that pattern to match, can you try with the start and end line markers too? `^[A-z]+\s[A-z]+\s\(34\)$`